# RobolectricTestRunner class not found after SDK and Gradle upgrade

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I upgraded recent legacy android application as follows,

CompileSDK 23 to 27
BuildTools  23.0.2 to 27.0.3
SupportLibVersion 23.0.2 to 27.1.1

below is my previous and current sourceset and test options code

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java']
    }
    robolectric {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java/')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}
```

Current version with "robolectric" changed to "androidTest" and "testOptions" task added, otherwise it wont compile.

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java']
    }
    androidTest {
        setRoot 'src/test/'
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java/')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

and this is how I integrated Robolectric

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2'
```

After making above changes, gradle sync succeeds, but Robolectric related classes are not recognized and could not be found.

I tried setting aapt2enabled as 'false', in this case gradle sync itself fails saying aapt2 is deprecated and will be removed in future. Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: `org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8`

Comment: This is a legacy application.Hence, kept the same version, however, tried version 3.8 too still same issue.Tried invalidating and restarting android studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your test class must not be in the "androidTest" directory but in the "Local unit test" directory (https://developer.android.com/studio/test/), i.e. "test" instead of "androidTest".

Because the "androidTest" directory is only for instrumented tests that run on a hardware device or emulator. And the advantage of Robolectric is that it does not need to run on a device or emulator. So you can either change "androidTest" to "test" in your gradle file or just remove the whole "androidTest {}" definition from your gradle file because src/test is the default path for the "Local unit test" directory.

I could fix the problem just by moving my test class from src/androidTest to src/test. But you will have to remove the "androidTest {}" definition from your gradle file, too.